# ¿Cómo crear un degradado de derecha a izquierda en CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Ya hice uno, pero lo hace de abajo hacia arriba, y lo que deseo es que el degrade vaya de derecha a izquierda. Intente con esto:

```
h1{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d87602, #d64322);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sólo te falta agregar el parámetro `to left` a la propiedad `-webkit-linear-gradient`

Así obtendrías un degradado de derecha a izquierda:

```
h1{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #d87602, #d64322);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div {
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #d87602 , #d64322); 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<p>Ejemplo</p>

<div id="div"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Aquí puedes leer más sobre la propiedad [linear-gradient en la w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Sumando a la respuesta anterior también lo podrías hacer por angulos,

Horizontales

```
#grad {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
}
#grad {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, yellow);
}
```

Verticales

```
#grad {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, red, yellow);
}
#grad {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, red, yellow);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Auque ya te respondieron la pregunta yo te agrego otra respuesta:

```css
h1{
 background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, red, #f06d06);

  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>hello</h1>
  
</body>
</html>
```

mas informacion mira aqui:
[css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)
[blog jonraasch](http://jonraasch.com/blog/graceful-degradation-with-css3)